# Trouble getting real time word count from html textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to html and javascript. I have a textbox and am trying to count the number of words, then displaying the count in real time. I do not understand what I am doing wrong in this, or how to correct it. textContent does not make much sense to me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      input[type='text'] {width:50px;}
      textarea {width:500px;height:300px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>The number of words is <span id="wordCount"></span></p>
    <textarea id="toCount"></textarea>
  </div>
      <script>

    document.getElementById('toCount').addEventListener('input', function () {
        var text = this.textContent,

        count = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;

        document.querySelector('.wordCount').textContent = count;

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error that I get right now says 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector should be #wordCount, and the textarea content can be accessed using value:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      input[type='text'] {width:50px;}
      textarea {width:500px;height:300px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>The number of words is <span id="wordCount"></span></p>
    <textarea id="toCount"></textarea>
  </div>
      <script>

    document.getElementById('toCount').addEventListener('input', function () {
        var text = this.value,
        count = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
        document.getElementById('wordCount').textContent = count;

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting null is: in selection, #wordCount is by Id, and .wordCount is by class. So `document.querySelector('.wordCount')` is returning null as there is no element with class wordCount.

The fix would be to simply change

```
document.querySelector('.wordCount').textContent = count;
```

to

```
document.querySelector('#wordCount').textContent = count;
```

Comment: Thank you! That completely fixed the error. Problem now is that the word count remains at 1 after entering anything.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 document.getElementById('toCount').addEventListener('input', function () {
        var text = this.value,

        count = text.trim().split(' ').length;

        document.querySelector('#wordCount').textContent = count;

    });
```

Here is the  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameshwartlopez/ms0Lfb9k/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    document.getElementById('toCount').addEventListener('input', function () {
       // var text = this.textContent,
        var text = this.value,

        count = text.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;

       // document.querySelector('#wordCount').textContent = count;
      document.querySelector('#wordCount').textContent = count;

    });
```